# Add a compile time only dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, dependency-management

I would like to add a dependency to an sbt project which is only used for compilation. Neither should it be on the runtime class path, nor should it be visible in any form in the published POM.

The idea is to add a stub only library ([OrangeExtensions](https://github.com/ymasory/OrangeExtensions)) so that the project can be compiled on any platform not just OS X.

Is it possible like this somehow:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.yuvimasory" % "orange-extensions" % "1.3.0" % ???
```

?

Comment: If your code depends on OrangeExtensions (can't be compiled without it), I would say that it is required at runtime as well.

Comment: @RadoBuransky `OrangeExtensions` is only a stub version of a library provided by Java on OS X by Apple. The API I am designing around it will precisely not call into this API when not on a Mac. In order to compile the project on a non-Mac, you need the stubs. Obviously the stubs are only a compile help.

Comment: You can use "provided" but it will show up.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can create a custom [dependency *configuration*](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#ivy-configurations) for this (actually, this is getting so common when you use private macros in your project, I wish SBT provided one).

In `build.sbt`:

```
// a 'compileonly' configuation
ivyConfigurations += config("compileonly").hide

// some compileonly dependency
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4" % "compileonly"

// appending everything from 'compileonly' to unmanagedClasspath
unmanagedClasspath in Compile ++= 
  update.value.select(configurationFilter("compileonly"))
```

That dependency will not appear in the `pom.xml` generated by `publish` and friends.

There *almost* is such a configuration available: the `provided` configuration. Except that `provided` ends up in the `pom.xml` as a dependency with `provided` scope. Also, `provided` means "the runtime itself provides this at runtime", not "this is not needed at runtime".

Comment: This doesn't work for me with a SBT macros project using 'dependsOn(macrosProject % "compileonly")' (otherwise [as per the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Macro-Projects.html)). Any ideas why not? The sub project isn't available at compile time.

Comment: While working w/ macros, this worked for some libraries for me (scala-reflections), but not for others (snakeyaml). I don't know why, but I wound up using pomPostProcess to get around the stragglers see: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13880582/455581). Hope this helps others blocked by compile time errors when excluding like this.

Comment: Note sbt1.0 requires a capital config item.  Use `
val CompileOnly = config("compileonly");
ivyConfigurations += CompileOnly.hide;`  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486527/622016