# Necessary to export Quasiquotes dependency for exported macro libraries on Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, dependency-management, scala-macros

I just updated a project which was using macro-paradise 2.0 snapshot under 2.10; with the final version of macro-paradise 2.0 it tells me the following when I compile under 2.10 (not 2.11):

> Quasiquotes in macro paradise for Scala 2.10 require a dependency on a supporting library. Add the following line to your SBT build: libraryDependencies += "org.scalamacros" %% "quasiquotes" % "2.0.0"

Now I'm worried because that dependency turns up as a regular dependency of my published Maven artifact. Is this really so? Or isn't Quasiquotes perhaps just a compile-time dependency that should not be needed for the published artifact?

If so, should I go [through these hoops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515325/add-a-compile-time-only-dependency-in-sbt) to get rid of the artifact, i.e. `% "compileonly"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros that use quasiquotes provided by recent versions of paradise for Scala 2.10, i.e. 2.0.0-M4+, including 2.0.0 and later ones, will almost always require the supporting library to be on classpath when expanding (very simple quasiquotes don't require the library, but that's quite rare).

Therefore if you want users of your library to also use macros that you've written with quasiquotes, you'll need to export `"org.scalamacros" %% "quasiquotes" % "2.x.y"` in your pom file or rely on someone else to provide this dependency for your users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just tried the approach in the linked question to create a special `"compileonly"` configuration and thus remove it from the exported POM. It was possible to use the library in Scala 2.10 even with Quasiquotes absent.