# Control which library dependency exported in SBT

Tags: sbt

I am looking for a way to control what library dependency exported, and what not. Something along those lines:

```
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.6" doNotExport
```

or perhaps at the point where the project is imported, like this:

```
lazy val main = Project(appName, file("."), settings = buildSettings)
  .dependsOn(ProjectRef(uri("../Utils"), "Utils").exceptLibraryDependency(organization="org.slf4j"))
```

Is there anything like this in SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it all depends on configurations. Default configurations expose dependencies again. So similar behavior can be achieved like this:

```
val compileOnly = config("compileOnly").hide

ivyConfigurations += compileOnly

unmanagedClasspath in Compile ++= 
  update.value.select(configurationFilter(compileOnly.name))

"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.6" % compileOnly
```

Note that this technique was descibed in an answer to [Add a compile time only dependency in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21516954/596816).

This question should be closed as a duplicate, but the bounty prevents this.