# Add a compile time only sub-project dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, scala-macros

I have a multi-project contains a private macro sub-project which's usage is limited to implement method body of other sub-projects. Neither should it be on the runtime classpath of other sub-projects, nor should it be visible in any form in the published POM of other sub-projects. So that other sbt project could use library from this project without knowing the macro sub-project.

For external dependency, I found this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515325/add-a-compile-time-only-dependency-in-sbt/21516954) works perfectly, but for sub-project when I trying to do the similar thing to `dependsOn`, sbt complains about configuration "compileonly" not found.

```
ivyConfigurations += config("compileonly").hide

val macro = Project("macro", file("macro"))

val lib = Project("lib", file("lib")).dependsOn(macro % "compile->compileonly")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is because the project doesn't have that config.

```
val CompileOnly = config("compileonly").hide    

ivyConfigurations += CompileOnly

val macro = Project("macro", file("macro")).configs(CompileOnly) // add config

val lib = Project("lib", file("lib")).dependsOn(macro % CompileOnly)
```

But then the problem is

> macro#macro_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: configuration not public in macro#macro_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: 'compileonly'. It was required from lib#lib_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT compile

The solution is

```
val CompileOnly = config("compileonly")

val macro = Project("macro", file("macro")).configs(CompileOnly)

val lib = Project("lib", file("lib")).dependsOn(macro % CompileOnly)
  .settings(ivyConfigurations += CompileOnly.hide)
```

---

You may also want to familiarize yourself with the `provided` configuration. It's a standard Maven/Ivy config that means that the jar will be provide on the classpath at runtime (e.g. like the JDK, or a servlet container), but not at compile time.

Comment: The `compile` task fails when I use this approach. When compiling `lib` it fails to find any of the classes in the `macro` project.

Answer (score 5):

```
val lib = Project("lib", file("lib")).dependsOn(macro % "compile-internal")
```

Just had this discussion last night...

Comment: Great spot, @pfn! It works not only for sub-project dependencies. It can be used for external dependencies too. Also, it has the "test-internal" tween for tests.